# How can I stop objects like images or tables to move to unwanted position?

Tags: tables, graphics

I'm currently writing something with overleaf latex but I'm having the issue that images or tables get set to positions I don't want it to.

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,angle=0]{src/pics/ex.PNG}
 \caption[caption]{Image}
\label{fig:caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
         &  \\
         & 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

So the table should appear right beneath the image but gets moved to the subsection above.

Is there a way to change this?

Comment: The only purpose of `figure` and `table` is to specify the content can be moved. `\begin{table}[]` actually specifies that it can be moved but is not allowed to be placed anywhere. Latex detects that and ignores the optional argument so uses the default position which is usually `tbp`   `\begin{figure}[htb]` has the effect of preventing the figure being placed on a float page so makes it more likely that it goes to the end of the document.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

[image]

Insert image and table in the same float, for example `figure` and than for table use `\captionof{table}{...}` defined in the `caption` or `capt-of` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,angle=0]{example-image-duck}%{src/pics/ex.PNG}
\caption[Image]{Long caption of the image}
\label{fig:image}

\bigskip % for adding vertical distance between image and table
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
    \hline
aaaa    &   bbbb        \\
ccccc   &   dd          \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\captionof{table}[Table]{Long caption of the Table}
    \label{tab:my_label}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum[12]
\end{document}
```